# How to find 95% CI of CI of Mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, central-limit-theorem

We know that the 95% confidence interval around the population mean is calculated as
x̄ ± 1.96* σ/√n,
where x̄ is the sample mean, σ is the sample standard deviation and n is the sample size.

On the other hand we know that reference interval is calculated as
x̄ ± 1.96* σ.

There are many known techniques to calculate the 95% CIs of reference limits
(CI of x̄ - 1.96*σ and CI of x̄ + 1.96* σ).

I would like to know, whether there is a methodology to calculate the 95% CI of 95% CI interval limits around the population mean (CI of x̄ - 1.96* σ/√n and CI of x̄ + 1.96* σ/√n)?

Thank You

Comment: This is a meaningless operation, because the CI of the mean is not a population property: it depends on $n$ and the sample (through $\bar x$). It is nevertheless possible to re-express and re-interpret it more generally as an interval to enclose both $\mu\pm\kappa\sigma$ where $\kappa$ is some fixed value; and this question can be interpreted as a kind of *tolerance interval.*  In light of this it's not at all apparent what underlying problem you are trying to solve. Please, then, describe that problem.

Comment: There's xkcd on that https://xkcd.com/2110/